# My project code not running in Xcode(15.3) but the same code running in Xcode 14.2 in swift how to fix in xcode 15.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode15

I have project which is perfectly running in Xcode 14.2 but the same code not running in Xcode 15.3 . but to make it run i tried below changes in Xcode 15.3 as per its error suggestions.

initially i have removed all pods and again added and pod install but then got so many cant fix errors--- that doesnt work so in 2nd process

I made all pods and target

1 )  `Minimum Deployments: increased from 8.0 to 12.0`

2 )  `Buildsettings > Excluded Architectures > Debug > iOSSimulatorSDK > arm64`

**now i got Error:** please guide me to run my code in xcode 15.3

> /Users/test/Desktop/app-ios/folder/MVC/Modal/ComposeMsgModal/MatchmultifacesModal.swift:10:8 No such module 'ObjectMapper'

[image]

and i done this in pod file

```
 # Enable DEBUG flag in Swift for SwiftTweaks
 post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'

      if target.name == 'EZSwiftExtensions'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
          end
      end
      if target.name == 'AlamofireImage' || target.name == 'NVActivityIndicatorView' ||  target.name == 'SwiftMessages' || target.name == 'Charts'
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
           end
       end
    end
  end
end
```

and i have below pods

[image]

Comment: It complains about ObjectMapper and there seems to be some issue with it and Xcode 15, see https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper/issues

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, thank you for above github issue link, that means i cant run the projects in xcode 15.3?  i have 2 projects with same issue :(

Comment: I only did some basic research here and have no personal experience with ObjectMapper, you have to draw the conclusions yourself and determine what to do unless someone with more experience of this library can help.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problems changing xcode versions and the pods arent being seen I just do:

- Pod deintegrate
- pod cache clean --all
- pod update

Futhermore, It's possible that the target that you are importing this module doesnt interacts with ObjectMapper, if you are using different modules give a different import for all of them. If there's more info and the pod commands doesnt work let me know ;)

Comment: you want me to update the pod by doing this `pod update`?  no i dont want updated pods.. bcz its not latest project. its bit 2019 project